# Characterization of the algebraic closure operator generating subuniverses

Tags: model-theory, universal-algebra

From "A course in Universal Algebra" of Burris and Sankappanavar.

Given an algebra $A$ define, for every $X \subseteq A$:

$Sg(X) = \bigcap\{B : X \subseteq B \ and \ B \ is \ a \ subuniverse \ of \ A\}$

$E(X) = X \cup \{f(a_1,...,a_n) : f \ is\ a \ fundamental \ nary \ operation \ on \ A \ and \ a_1,...,a_n \in X\}$.

Then define $E^n(X)$ for $n \ge 0$ by:

$E^0(X) = X $

$E^{n+1}(X) = E(E^n(X))$.

It is possible to prove that:

$Sg(X) = X \cup E(X) \cup E^2(X) \cup ··· $

**Question**

I would like to know how the last sentence is shown.

Comment: There are two directions: $Sg(X)\supseteq X\cup E(X)\cup ...$ and $X\cup E(X)\cup ...\supseteq Sg(X)$. Do you understand either of them already? (The first is intuitively easiest in my opinion.)

Comment: $X \cup E(X) \cup ... \subseteq Sg(X)$ we can show that the opposite would imply that Sg (X) is not closed under at least one fundamental function, a contradiction. Furthermore the closed set system generated by $Sg(X)$ is closed under arbitrary intersections and unions of chains, both necessary and sufficient conditions to prove that $Sg(X)$ is an algebraic closure operator. But i can't derive a proof of $Sg(X) \subseteq X \cup E(X) \cup ...$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove that $Sg(X)$ is a subset of $X\cup E(X)\cup\dots$, it suffices to prove that $B:=X\cup E(X)\cup\dots$ is a subuniverse of $A$ containing $X$ (because then this particular $B$ appears in the big intersection defining $Sg(X)$, so that $Sg(X)\subseteq B$).

So let us take an $n$-ary fundamental operation $f$ and $a_1,\dots,a_n\in B$. Since $E^k(X)\subseteq E^{k+1}(X)$ for all $k$, we have that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ all belong to the same $E^k(X)$ for some large enough $k$. Now we get by definition of $E$ that $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in E(E^k(X))= E^{k+1}(X)\subseteq B$. Therefore, $B$ is a subuniverse.